# Building reliably structure from XML file

Tags: java, xml, boolean, boolean-expression, reliability

I need to describe some reliably structures in XML file and than load it into program, parse it, and build boolean function of this structure. Below I attached an image of sample structure.
[image: sample structure]

How can I describe this in XML file?
Every single part of this model remains in a certain state. False of True. So if we have elements 1 = true, 2 = false and rest equals to true it will be working but if element 1 is false whole this structure isn't working.
How can I parse this XML file into boolean function describing that kind of structures?

Comment: Do you want to get to `if (e1 && (e2 || e3) && ((e4 && (e5 || e6)) || e7 || (e8 && e9)) && e10 && e11)` ?

Comment: i want to build this equation (e1 && (e2 || e3) && ((e4 && (e5 || e6)) || e7 || (e8 && e9)) && e10 && e11)
and be able to get result of it